# Web Config Transformation Issues

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, web-config

I have a web.config file and a web.release.config file.  In web config I define a Mail Queue Folder:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MailQueue" value="\MailQueue\"/>
  </appSettings>
```

And this works correctly as long as I publish to IIS in "debug" mode.

I want to use a different folder for production, so in web.release.config I try to replace `MailQueue` with:

```
    <appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <add key="MailQueue" value="\MailQueueProd\"/>
    </appSettings>
```

However, when I try and publish in "release" mode the `MailQueue` value does not work correctly.  Even if I set web.release.config to be the same path like:

```
      <appSettings>
        <add key="MailQueue" value="\MailQueue\"/>
      </appSettings>
```

The mail queue stops working.  Am I using this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace what you have in web.release.config with this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add
      key="MailQueue"
      value="\MailQueueProd\"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

Somewhere in the document hierarchy above or at this code, you also need the following XML namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
```

Here's the documentation page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx